# Setup QThread with QTimer and QSerial

Tags: multithreading, timer, serial-port, qthread

I'm trying to set my QSerial port in a separated thread so that my main program  to keep it isolated from the GUI processing delay.

I have been able to start the thread and I used a QTimer to restart the ::run() method because i couldn't use a while loop.

In my main i move my object to a new thread and start my thread when a new connection is opened. When the signal started() from my threadComPortRx is emitted, I launch the timer that will make a loop in my thread

**Main :**

```
#include "validation_board.h"

Validation_Board::Validation_Board()
{    
    valid_comm = new ValidationCommunication();
    threadComPortRx = new QThread();

    valid_dataTreatment->moveToThread(threadDataTreatment);
    valid_comm->moveToThread(threadComPortRx);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(testsignal(QByteArray)), valid_comm, SLOT(dataSend(QByteArray)));
    connect(threadComPortRx, SIGNAL(started()), valid_comm, SLOT(communicationManager()));
}


void Validation_Board::openSerialPort(QString comPort, int portSpeed)
{
    valid_comm->openSerialPort("COM10", 9600);
    threadComPortRx->start();
}
```

My class running in a separate thread looks like :

**validationcommunication.h :**

```
#ifndef VALIDATIONCOMMUNICATION_H
#define VALIDATIONCOMMUNICATION_H
#include <QQueue>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QTimer>
#include "comport.h"

class ValidationCommunication : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ValidationCommunication();
    void run();
   // QSerialPort *_validComport;
    ComPort *_validComport;
    //void dataReceived(QByteArray rxData);
    ~ValidationCommunication();
signals:
    void dataReceived(QByteArray rxData);
    void sendData(QByteArray data);

public slots:
    void openSerialPort(QString comPort, int portSpeed);
    void closeSerialPort();
    bool getIsOpen();
    void dataSend(QByteArray data);
    void sendCommand(QByteArray txFrame);
    bool readData(QByteArray *responseBuffer);
    void timerCallback();
    void communicationManager();

private:
    bool dataToSend;
    QByteArray dataTx;
    QQueue<QByteArray> queue;
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
};

#endif // VALIDATIONCOMMUNICATION_H
```

**validationcommunication.c :**

```
#include "validationcommunication.h"

ValidationCommunication::ValidationCommunication()
{
    _validComport = new ComPort("COM10", 9600);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerCallback()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendData(QByteArray)), _validComport, SLOT(write(QByteArray)));
}

ValidationCommunication::~ValidationCommunication()
{
    delete _validComport;
}

void ValidationCommunication::openSerialPort(QString comPort, int portSpeed)
{

    _validComport = new ComPort(comPort, portSpeed);
    _validComport->openSerialPort();
}

void ValidationCommunication::dataSend(QByteArray data)
{
    dataToSend = true;
    dataTx = data;
    qCritical() << "Test";
}

void ValidationCommunication::timerCallback()
{
    start();
}


void ValidationCommunication::communicationManager()
{
    timer->start(1000);
}

void ValidationCommunication::run()
{
    QByteArray responseBuffer, test;

    qCritical() << "Loop : " << QThread::currentThread();

    responseBuffer.clear();

    if(dataToSend)
    {
    qCritical() << "Send data :" << dataTx << " from Thread :" << QThread::currentThread();
        sendCommand(dataTx);
    }
    dataToSend = false;

   // exec();
}

void ValidationCommunication::sendCommand(QByteArray txFrame)
{
    emit sendData(txFrame);
}
```

My class ComPort is just a class to manage a QSerialPort object :

```
**ComPort.h :**
#ifndef COMPORT_H
#define COMPORT_H

#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
//#include <QApplication>

class ComPort : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum e_Usage
    {
        BLE,
        OTHER
    };

    ComPort(QString portName, qint32 baudRate, e_Usage usage = OTHER, QSerialPort::FlowControl flowControl = QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    void closeSerialPort();
    void openSerialPort();
    bool clear();
    QByteArray readyRead();
    qint64 bytesAvailable();
    QByteArray writeAndRead(QByteArray data);
    bool getIsOpen();

    virtual ~ComPort();
    void disconnectReadyRead();
    QByteArray Read(int size, int timeout);
    bool waitForReadyRead(int timeout);

public slots:
        void write(QByteArray data);
protected slots:

    void readyReadBLE();

signals:
    void dataReceivedBLE(quint8 hilen, quint8 clas, quint8 method, QByteArray data);
    void dataReceived(QByteArray data);

protected:
    QSerialPort *_serialPort;
    QString _portName;
    qint32 _baudRate;
    bool _isOpen;
    QMutex _mx;
    e_Usage _usage;
    QSerialPort::FlowControl  _flowControl;
};

#endif // COMPORT_H
```

**ComPort.c :**

```
#include "comport.h"

ComPort::ComPort(QString portName, qint32 baudRate, e_Usage usage, QSerialPort::FlowControl flowControl)
{
    _usage = usage;
    _portName = portName;
    _baudRate = baudRate;
    _isOpen = false;
    _serialPort = NULL;
    _flowControl = flowControl;
}

ComPort::~ComPort()
{
    if (_serialPort)
        delete _serialPort;
}

void ComPort::closeSerialPort()
{
    qDebug() << "CLOSE :" << _portName;
    if (_serialPort && _serialPort->isOpen())
    {
        _serialPort->clear();
        _serialPort->close();
    }
    _isOpen = false;
}

void ComPort::openSerialPort()
{
    _serialPort = new QSerialPort(this);
        _serialPort->setPortName(_portName);
    _serialPort->setBaudRate(_baudRate);
    _serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    _serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    _serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    _serialPort->setFlowControl(_flowControl);
    if (_serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        qDebug() << "Connected :" << _portName;
        _isOpen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        qWarning() << "Error while opening" << _portName <<":" << _serialPort->errorString();
        closeSerialPort();
    }
}


void ComPort::write(QByteArray data)
{
    if (_serialPort)
    {
        qint64 res = _serialPort->write(data.data(), data.length());
        //_serialPort->flush();
        if (res <= 0)
            qDebug() << _serialPort->errorString();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I want to send data by emmiting the signal sendData nothing happens altough it is connected to the write slot to my ComPort slot write.